# How to open many pages with bash?

Tags: bash

I am working on one of my test web projects and every time I finish my work and want to rest, I have to close 3, 4, 5, or more sessions on my termux. I'm using vim, and I have to go to the working directory and there open vim (opening 4 or 5 files in 4 or 5 sessions every time I'm going to start my work). But I wanted to make it simpler, so if I could just write a bash script that would open all those sessions for me, that would be great. At first I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /storage/emulated/0/1_code/1_web/server/root
httpd 
vi index.php
$SHELL
```

And that works well, but I want to open more files using this bash script.

I tried to create many bash scripts like the one above and then created a wrapper script which runs all those scripts but it didn't work for me. Can anyone help me with that?
Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `tmux`? You can create and load a file that automatically splits your window into panes and launches commands in them.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know what is tmux. I'm gonna search more about it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the script that failed. Also, please explain how you want this to work. Do you want multiple,  separate terminals each with one file opened in `vi`? One terminal with tabs? Something else? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`vim` lets you save your current session with

```
:mksession my-session.vim
```

Then you can restore it with:

```
vim -S my-session.vim
```

As to how to restore or configure a `tmux` session, I'll let others answer as I'm a `screen` user myself, but if it's like in `screen`, that would involve starting `tmux` with a custom start-up file that runs different commands (including that `vim -S` one) in different windows / panes.